# Which diodes are used in a high amperage rectifying circuit? (4007 are 1A rated) and other components

Tags: power-supply, diodes

I recently designed a power supply that was good for about 700mA power and used these diodes 
https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds28002.pdf They are 4007 diodes. As I am checking the datasheets for my 5A power supply I'm noticing that they are good for up to 1A so I was wondering which diodes are commonly used with high amperage 50 Hz / 60 Hz power supplies? What other components can I expect to change with this change in amperage? Looking forward to your responses

EDIT: this is a standard 50Hz / 60Hz power supply .. buck converter becuase it's high amperage. 
That is what i'm referrring to in this question, as replacement for 1N4007 diode.

I am also making a different 5A power supply.. which in this case requires Schottky diodes rated for high frequency and 3-4A, in a full bridge rectifier

thanks

Comment: Your question does not make it clear whether you are designing a 50 / 60 Hz power supply or an SMPS. What exactly do you mean by "*... to instead rectify the voltage BEFORE it goes through the transformer.*"?

Comment: rectifying AC to DC before it passes through the transformer. ( using a diode that can do 1A at 120V at the start of circuit instead of using a diode that does 3-4A at 5V after the voltage has been stepped down.)  - using these in a full bridge

Comment: Notice that you didn't answer my question regarding mains frequency or SMPS. You *are* aware that transformers work on AC and not DC, aren't you?

Comment: only slightly confused. Appreciate the comments. i saw briefly something like that circuit rectifying 120V AC to 120V DC before passing through transformer so i was referencing it. Transformers only transform from AC.

Comment: Your question is still very confused but you have accepted an answer already so it is unlikely that anyone else will try to answer.

Comment: 1N4007 are not suitable for use at typical SMPS frequencies. | Selector guide at eg www.digikey.com will allow many suitable diodes to be identified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[1N540x](http://www.vishay.com/docs/88516/1n5400.pdf) is a common 3A diode, so with a full bridge you can get 6A. Above a few amperes you should consider Schottky diodes, at least at lower supply voltages.

You can also get inexpensive [packaged bridges](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/427/gbpc12-1768029.pdf) with ~17A diodes rated for 35A that can be directly bolted to a heatsink.

Comment: schottky diodes are what i am going to use before the flyback transformer. Was thinking about the switching speeds, because i am planning to use high frequency. this is what i have in mind for either application. These are both for AFTER the transformer (40V max) https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/348/rbr5lam40atr-e-1801371.pdf and 5A each (10A max load)

Comment: None of these are acceptable for much higher than audio frequencies. Ultrafast and Schottky diodes are required for reasonable efficiency at tens of kHz and higher.

Comment: Exactly, i may not have been clear about that understanding. the linked is a Schottky diode